# calling different types of html elements

Tags: python, html, flask, radio-button

i want to call radio buttons along with text inputs in one statement like this in app.py:

question = quickQuizQuestions(request.form['TFtxtarea'], request.form.getlist('TFquestion'), request.form['MCQtxtarea'], request.form['MCQanswer'], request.form['txta'], request.form['txtb'], request.form['txtc'])

but it gives me error

sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: INSERT INTO quick_quiz_questions ("TFquestion", "TFanswer", "MCQquestion", "MCQanswer", "OptionA", "OptionB", "OptionC") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('saudi already', ['True'], 'what are u', 'c', 'saudi ', 'spanish', 'german')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)

all fields are text inputs except for TFanswer which is radio button

here is full app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, url_for, redirect, session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import ctypes
import sqlite3

from sqlalchemy import sql, create_engine, select, MetaData, Table


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////Users/AFEER/projects/hello_flask/database.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "random string"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.app = app

#questions table
class quickQuizQuestions(db.Model):
    def __init__(self, TFquestion, TFanswer, MCQquestion, MCQanswer, OptionA, OptionB, OptionC):
        self.TFquestion = TFquestion
        self.TFanswer = TFanswer
        self.MCQquestion = MCQquestion
        self.MCQanswer = MCQanswer
        self.OptionA = OptionA
        self.OptionB = OptionB
        self.OptionC = OptionC
    id = db.Column('question_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    TFquestion = db.Column(db.String(900))
    TFanswer = db.Column(db.String(1))
    MCQquestion = db.Column(db.String(900))
    MCQanswer = db.Column(db.String(1))
    OptionA = db.Column(db.String(1))
    OptionB = db.Column(db.String(1))
    OptionC = db.Column(db.String(1))

#students answers table
class studentAnswer(db.Model):
    def __init__(self, student_id, student_name, student_answer, postedQuestion):
        self.student_id = student_id
        self.student_name = student_name
        self.student_answer = student_answer
        self.postedQuestion = postedQuestion
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # student_id = password
    student_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    student_name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    student_answer = db.Column(db.String(1))
    postedQuestion = db.Column(db.String(900))

@app.route('/result')
def result():
        return render_template('result.html', quickQuizQuestions=quickQuizQuestions.query.all())



@app.route('/quickQuizList', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def quickQuizList():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['TFtxtarea'] or request.form['MCQtxtarea']:
            question = quickQuizQuestions(request.form['TFtxtarea'], request.form.getlist('TFquestion'), request.form['MCQtxtarea'], request.form['MCQanswer'], request.form['txta'], request.form['txtb'], request.form['txtc'])
            db.session.add(question)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Record was successfully added')
            return render_template("result.html")

        else:
            flash('Please enter all the fields', 'error')

    return render_template("quickQuizList.html")


@app.route('/test')
def test():
    # if request.form['TFtxtarea']:
    #     return render_template("TFpagequestion.html")
    #
    # if request.form['MCQtxtarea']:
    #     return render_template("MCQpagequestion.html")

        return render_template('test.html', quickQuizQuestions=quickQuizQuestions.query.order_by(-quickQuizQuestions.id).limit(1).all())


if __name__ =='__main__':
    db.create_all()
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

here is quickQuizList where html elements:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tools</title>
<style>

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3F3B72;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
.header-right {
  float: right;
}
.header a.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;

}
.header a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#buttonClos{
box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #f0f7fa;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #33bdef 5%, #019ad2 100%);
    background-color:#33bdef;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #057fd0;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:7px 18px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 0px #5b6178;display:inline-block;

}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #FFFAFA;
}

.form{padding:20px;
font-size:20px;
}
</style>
    <script>
function quickQuiz() {

        var questionType = document.getElementById("questionType").value;

<!--        TF elements-->
        var TFtxtarea = document.getElementById("TFtxtarea");
        var label1 = document.getElementById("label1");
        var Tanswer = document.getElementById("Tanswer");
        var Fanswer = document.getElementById("Fanswer");
        var labelT = document.getElementById("labelT");
        var labelF = document.getElementById("labelF");
        var TFsubmit = document.getElementById("TFsubmit");

<!--        MCQ elements-->
        var MCQtxtarea = document.getElementById("MCQtxtarea");
        var a = document.getElementById("a");
        var b = document.getElementById("b");
        var c = document.getElementById("c");
        var txta = document.getElementById("txta");
        var txtb = document.getElementById("txtb");
        var txtc = document.getElementById("txtc");
        var MCQsubmit = document.getElementById("MCQsubmit");
        var label2 = document.getElementById("label2");
        var MCQanswer = document.getElementById("MCQanswer");

        if(questionType == "TF" || questionType == "tf")
        {
            TFtxtarea.style.display="block";
            label1.style.display="block";
            TFsubmit.style.display="block";
            Tanswer.style.display="block";
            Fanswer.style.display="block";
            labelT.style.display="block";
            labelF.style.display="block";

            MCQtxtarea.style.display="none";
            a.style.display="none";
            b.style.display="none";
            c.style.display="none";
            txta.style.display="none";
            txtb.style.display="none";
            txtc.style.display="none";
            MCQsubmit.style.display="none";
            label2.style.display="none";
            MCQanswer.style.display="none";
        }

        if(questionType == "MCQ" || questionType == "mcq")
        {
            MCQtxtarea.style.display="block";
            a.style.display="block";
            b.style.display="block";
            c.style.display="block";
            txta.style.display="block";
            txtb.style.display="block";
            txtc.style.display="block";
            MCQsubmit.style.display="block";
            label2.style.display="block";
            MCQanswer.style.display="block";

            TFtxtarea.style.display="none";
            label1.style.display="none";
            Tanswer.style.display="none";
            Fanswer.style.display="none";
            labelT.style.display="none";
            labelF.style.display="none";
            TFsubmit.style.display="none";
        }
  }
</script>
</head>
{%- for category, message in get_flashed_messages(with_categories = true) %}
         <div class = "alert alert-danger">
            {{ message }}
         </div>
      {%- endfor %}
<div class="header">
    <a class="logo">QuickQuiz</a>

</div>
<form action = "{{ request.path }}" method = "POST">
<div  class="form">
   <p> Enter the question type (TF/MCQ):</p>
    <input type="text" id="questionType" placeholder="TF or MCQ:">
    <br><br>
<label style="border:inset" id="submitQuestionType" onclick="quickQuiz()"> Submit</label>
    <br><br>

    <textarea name="TFtxtarea" id="TFtxtarea" style="display:none" placeholder="Type your TF question here"></textarea>
    <br><br>
    <label style="display:none" id="label1">Choose the correct answer:</label>

    <input style="display:none"type="radio" id="Tanswer" name="TFquestion" value="True" >
    <label id="labelT" style="display:none">(True)</label><br>
    <input style="display:none" type="radio" id="Fanswer" name="TFquestion" value="False">
    <label id="labelF" style="display:none">(False)</label><br>


    <input style="display:none" id="TFsubmit" type = "submit" value = "Submit & Post" />

    <textarea name="MCQtxtarea" id="MCQtxtarea" style="display:none" placeholder="Type your MCQ question here"></textarea>
    <br>
    <label id="a" style="display:none">Option A</label>
    <input type="text" name="txta" id="txta" style="display:none"> <br>
    <label id="b" style="display:none">Option B</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtb" id="txtb" style="display:none"> <br>
    <label id="c" style="display:none">Option C</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtc" id="txtc" style="display:none">

    <br>
    <label id="label2" style="display:none">Enter the correct answer</label>
    <input type="text" id="MCQanswer" name="MCQanswer" style="display:none">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="MCQsubmit" style="display:none" value="Submit & Post">

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe because your 2nd parameter is a list? parameters: ('saudi already', ['True'], 'what are u', 'c', 'saudi ', 'spanish', 'german') . The error says parameter 1 though but perhaps they start to count from 0? You get it with a list getting thing so no wonder it is a list, request.form.getlist('TFquestion')

Comment: TFanswer is a radio button that's the only way to access the value by using request.form.getlist('TFquestion') & the reset of the elements are input text thus incompatible... I don't know how to solve it

Comment: Maybe you should take 30minutes to complete a Python introductory tutorial to learn the basics. This is how you can take the first element from a list to a single variable, which should work for your statement: `mylist = ['True']; myitem = mylist[0]`